I need Assistance in proving that a particular sequence is strictly decreasing.
let $g : \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a sequence defined by $$g(n) = \frac{(c\log(1+\log(1+n)))^{n-1} + 1}{n}$$ where $1\ge c>0$ It seems like this sequence is strictly decreasing, I guess one could take the same function on the reals and compute its derivative, but I was wondering if there is a particular inequality that would give a shorter/more elegant proof, that would help showing $g(n+1)<g(n)$. Thank you in advance :).
Edit: It seems I am quite wrong. Now I wonder if there are any c for which $g(n)$ is decreasing.

If $c>1$ this sequence cannot be decreasing: it tends to $\infty$.

Thank you very much, it seems I overlooked that. Could you make a comment about how one could show it for $c\in (0,1]$ ?

Even for $c=0.7$ this is wrong: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%5Cfrac%7B%280.7%5Clog%281%2B%5Clog%281%2Bn%29%29%29%5E%7Bn-1%7D+%2B+1%7D%7Bn%7D++from+n%3D0+to+30

desmos Thank you for the reply, either something is wrong with Desmos (here I've put c =1) or I'm just not seeing it carefully. But wolfram shows it right wolfram. @AnneBauval

Yes I know, I did the same query before (c=1). What I am reporting is even worse (c=0.7)

@AnneBauval, Yes, I saw the link that you gave. Thank you very much for pointing out the error :). Now I wonder if there are some c for which this guy decreases..
